# Is it suitable to use DSSS in a narrow-band channel for a power-starved system

Tags: digital-modes, cw, fm

I want to build a system that can transmit data through 2-way radios **as far as possible**. I use the "line-in" as the input of the baseband signal in the transmitter and use the "audio out" as the output in the receiver. The RF modulation scheme seems to be a **NBFM** and the bandwidth of their audio input and output are about **2kHz-4kHz**. The bit rate should be **more than 64bits/s**. I think there are many systems that work like this.

I was plan to use **64-MSK with RS code and interleaving** at first but one of my workmate insist **DSSS+BPSK without any coding**. Personally, I don't think DSSS is a good choice in this situation.

I want to know who is right? Which one is better and why. Are there any mature schemes that I can choose?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, "Narrow band" and "DSSS" do not usually go together...